# problema a la hora de escrolear en mi sitio web

Tags: html, css

En resumen es una pagina para demostrar la evolución de la tecnología. pero el problema es que cuando escroleo, va trabado. a continuación adjunto el código entero. Probe en varios navegadores pero sucede lo mismo y no se cual es el error que causa eso. (para evitar problemas, quite los enlaces) el codigo en si, es muy simple, lo reconozco. pero no es normal que suceda eso, ya que he hecho otras cosas que requerian escrolear, pero no se trababan asi. si alguien lo soluciona y me explica, lo agradezco mucho.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>

    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tektur&display=swap');
        .title {
        font-family: tektur;
        
    }
    body {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:svgjs='http://svgjs.dev/svgjs' width='1440' height='900' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 1440 900'%3e%3cg mask='url(%26quot%3b%23SvgjsMask1020%26quot%3b)' fill='none'%3e%3crect width='1440' height='900' x='0' y='0' fill='%231a4e83'%3e%3c/rect%3e%3cpath d='M0 0L825.59 0L0 671.9z' filter='url(%23SvgjsFilter1021)' fill='%232d409e'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M0 900L825.59 900L0 228.10000000000002z' filter='url(%23SvgjsFilter1021)' fill='%232d409e'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M1440 900L614.41 900L1440 228.10000000000002z' filter='url(%23SvgjsFilter1021)' fill='%232d409e'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M1440 0L614.41 0L1440 671.9z' filter='url(%23SvgjsFilter1021)' fill='%232d409e'%3e%3c/path%3e%3c/g%3e%3cdefs%3e%3cmask id='SvgjsMask1020'%3e%3crect width='1440' height='900' fill='white'%3e%3c/rect%3e%3c/mask%3e%3cfilter height='130%25' id='SvgjsFilter1021'%3e%3cfeGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='5' result='TopLeftG'%3e%3c/feGaussianBlur%3e%3cfeOffset dx='-5' dy='-5' in='TopLeftG' result='TopLeftO'%3e%3c/feOffset%3e%3cfeComponentTransfer in='TopLeftO' result='TopLeftC'%3e%3cfeFuncA type='linear' slope='0.7'%3e%3c/feFuncA%3e%3c/feComponentTransfer%3e%3cfeGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='5' result='TopRightG'%3e%3c/feGaussianBlur%3e%3cfeOffset dx='5' dy='-5' in='TopRightG' result='TopRightO'%3e%3c/feOffset%3e%3cfeComponentTransfer in='TopRightO' result='TopRightC'%3e%3cfeFuncA type='linear' slope='0.7'%3e%3c/feFuncA%3e%3c/feComponentTransfer%3e%3cfeGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='5' result='BottomLeftG'%3e%3c/feGaussianBlur%3e%3cfeOffset dx='-5' dy='5' in='BottomLeftG' result='BottomLeftO'%3e%3c/feOffset%3e%3cfeComponentTransfer in='BottomLeftO' result='BottomLeftC'%3e%3cfeFuncA type='linear' slope='0.7'%3e%3c/feFuncA%3e%3c/feComponentTransfer%3e%3cfeGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='5' result='BottomRightG'%3e%3c/feGaussianBlur%3e%3cfeOffset dx='5' dy='5' in='BottomRightG' result='BottomRightO'%3e%3c/feOffset%3e%3cfeComponentTransfer in='BottomRightO' result='BottomRightC'%3e%3cfeFuncA type='linear' slope='0.7'%3e%3c/feFuncA%3e%3c/feComponentTransfer%3e%3cfeMerge%3e%3cfeMergeNode in='TopLeftC'%3e%3c/feMergeNode%3e%3cfeMergeNode in='TopRightC'%3e%3c/feMergeNode%3e%3cfeMergeNode in='BottomLeftC'%3e%3c/feMergeNode%3e%3cfeMergeNode in='BottomRightC'%3e%3c/feMergeNode%3e%3cfeMergeNode in='SourceGraphic'%3e%3c/feMergeNode%3e%3c/feMerge%3e%3c/filter%3e%3c/defs%3e%3c/svg%3e");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    * {
        color: yellow;
    }
    p, li {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    header {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px black;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        width: fit-content;
        border-radius: 8px;


    }
   #contenido {
    width: 500px;
   }
   #right {
        float: right;
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 0px;

   }
   fieldset {
    border-radius: 15px;
    color:#000 ;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
    font-family: tektur;
    width: 500px;
    
   }
   #more {
    width: 1330px;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px  black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
   }
   footer {
    box-shadow: 3PX 3PX 10PX BLACK;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
   }
    </style>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>La nueva era</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="title">Nada es como antes</h1> <br>
        
    </header>
    <main id='contenido'>
        <!-- Aquí va el contenido -->
    <h2 class="title">Todo cambio</h2>
    <p>Es evidente que el mercado de la tecnologia se renueva cada vez más. Por ejemplo, ya no se usa sms, todos usan Whatsapp, pero no es una garantia de que no se remplaze por nada. 
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>Whatsapp, por ejemplo esta poco a poco siendo remplazado por Telegram</li>
        <li>Chrome, no es una mala opcion, sin embargo edge, de microsoft, quiza si le das una oportunidad, te resulte mucho mejor, ademas, combina mejor con windows.</li>
    </ul>
    </main>
    <div id="right">
        <h3>contactos</h3>
        <fieldset>
            <legend><strong>Datos de contacto:</strong></legend>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href=""></a></li>

            </ul>
            <p>Unete a esta comunidad. aca podras sugerir cosas nuevas, para este sitio web y futuros. Ademas, enterarte de novedades u opinar sobre estas.</p>
            <p>Solo debes descargar telegram y unirte. Haras un dos por uno! Ya que probaras telegram y me apoyaras!</p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="half"></div>
    <div id="more">
        <p>Como se pudo leer arriba, de una manera distinta, todo avanza y evoluxiona a un ritmo impresionante. Tanto asi que el mismisimo Whatsapp, ya nos es la unica opcion en cuanto a app de mensajeria. Quizas tampoco sea la mejor opcion. Tan solo viendo videos de funciones "nuevas" de Whatsapp, puedes ver como la gente dice que Telegram ya lo tenia hace rato.
        Pero, por otro lado, no todo el mundo usa Telegram ya que, la misma no posee publicidad, o al menos no tanta como para que la gente se de cuenta de las ventajas que Telegram puede tener por encima de Whatsapp. Continuando, Chrome es muy buen navegador, pero Edge quizas pueda sorprenderte. Este puede ser mas compatible con tu computador windows. <br>
        Poco a poco vas a notar un mejor rendimiento en tu computador si utilizas este navegador, ya que pertenece a Microsoft igual que Windows, por otro lado, tiene una interfaz muy buena y las cosas estan a un alcance mejor gracias a la barra lateral. <br>
        Habro un espacio para mencionar a Facebook, a muchos les costara creer que es una muy buena red social, pero los jovenes simplemente prefieren decantarse por Instagram.
        </p>
    </div>
    <footer><a href=""></a>
    
    
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo eso de que "va trabado", a que te refieres. A mi tu ejemplo me va perfect el scroll